# I have Converted my jsonObject into JsonArray how can i loop it

Tags: java, android, json

1. I am trying to convert my jsonArray I have succesfully able to get
   the data but how to loop my jsonArray so i can get complete detail
   in listview. And how can I append my data if there is multiple data
   in same object and parse it into listview.
2. I have converted my jsonObject into Jsonarray

   ```
   public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           return JsonParser.makeHttpUrlConnectionRequest(url, getParam());
       }

       private List<NameValuePair> getParam() {
           SharedPreferences preferences = ReportActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.detail), MODE_PRIVATE);
           enroll_no = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.loginenroll), "");

           List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<>();
           list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enroll_no", enroll_no));

           // Log.e("List", String.valueOf(list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enroll_no",enroll))));
           Log.e("Request in Profile", String.valueOf(list));
           return list;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String httpresponse) {
           super.onPostExecute(httpresponse);
           if (httpresponse == null) {
               Toast.makeText(ReportActivity.this, "Unable to Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else if (httpresponse.equals("error")) {
               Toast.makeText(ReportActivity.this, "Internal Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           } else {

               try {
                   responseParameter = new JSONObject(httpresponse);
                   JSONObject fees_history = responseParameter.getJSONObject("fees_history");

                   //  JSONObject RC1 = fees_history.getJSONObject("RC1");
                   Iterator rc1 = fees_history.keys();
                   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                   int i = 0;
                   while (rc1.hasNext()) {
                       String key = (String) rc1.next();
                       jsonArray.put(fees_history.get(key));

                       JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i++);
                       JSONObject heading = object.getJSONObject("heading");
                       JSONArray details = object.getJSONArray("details");
                       Log.e("details", details.toString());
                       String Amount = heading.getString("Amount");
                       String date = heading.getString("date");
                       String Reciept = heading.getString("Reciept");

                     //  for (int j = 0; j < details.length(); j++) {

                           JSONObject detail = details.getJSONObject(i);

                           String Month = detail.getString("Month");

                           String Amountt = detail.getString("Amount");
                           Log.e("Amount", Amountt);
                           Log.e("Month", Month);

                           Unpaid_fees_detail unpaid_fees_detail = new Unpaid_fees_detail(Reciept, date, Amount,Amountt,Month);
                           unpaid_fees_details.add(unpaid_fees_detail);
                       }

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               //  Log.e("RC1",RC1.toString());

                //   Log.e("fees_history", fees_history.toString());

               }
               Unpaid_fees_detail_adapter unpaid_fees_detail_adapter = new Unpaid_fees_detail_adapter(ReportActivity.this, unpaid_fees_details);
               listView.setAdapter(unpaid_fees_detail_adapter);
           }

       }
   ```

   And here is my JsonArray

   ```
   [  
      {  
         "heading":{  
            "Amount":11800,
            "Reciept":"RC1",
            "date":"29-07-2017"
         },
         "details":[  
            {  
               "unique_id":"75",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Aug",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"yes",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-06-30",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30",
               "updated_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1000",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Aug",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Monthly Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Dec",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1000",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Dec",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Monthly Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:21:12",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:21:12"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Feb",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:21:12",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:21:12"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"75",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1000",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Term 1",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Monthly Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-06-30",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30",
               "updated_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"75",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"7000",
               "bal":"3000",
               "Month":"Admission Fee",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"One time",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-06-30",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30",
               "updated_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC1",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1500",
               "bal":"1500",
               "Month":"Admission Fee",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"One time",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "heading":{  
            "Amount":200,
            "Reciept":"RC2",
            "date":"30-06-2017"
         },
         "details":[  
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC2",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Jan",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"75",
               "Reciept":"RC2",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Jul",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"yes",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-06-30",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30",
               "updated_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "heading":{  
            "Amount":1100,
            "Reciept":"RC3",
            "date":"30-06-2017"
         },
         "details":[  
            {  
               "unique_id":"75",
               "Reciept":"RC3",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1000",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Jul",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Monthly Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-06-30",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30",
               "updated_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"75",
               "Reciept":"RC3",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Jun",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"yes",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-06-30",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30",
               "updated_at":"2017-06-30 14:08:30"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "heading":{  
            "Amount":2100,
            "Reciept":"RC4",
            "date":"29-07-2017"
         },
         "details":[  
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC4",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1000",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Jun",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Monthly Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC4",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"100",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Nov",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Bus Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:20:52"
            },
            {  
               "unique_id":"65",
               "Reciept":"RC4",
               "Gr_num":"1355",
               "Amount":"1000",
               "bal":"0",
               "Month":"Nov",
               "year":"2017",
               "fee_type":"Monthly Fee",
               "pay_mode":"cash",
               "cheque_num":"0",
               "lflag":"no",
               "late_fee":"0",
               "discount":"0",
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2017-07-29",
               "bank_name":"",
               "cheque_date":"0000-00-00",
               "is_cheq_msg_send":"0",
               "is_active":"1",
               "cheq_msg":"",
               "created_at":"2017-07-29 12:21:12",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-29 12:21:12"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
   ```

Comment: I would suggest look into Gson library and Retrofit

Answer (score 1):

You Just To make `fori` loop

```
ArrayList<DetailItem> detailItems = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray details = response.getJSONArray("details");
if (details != null) {
    for (int k = 0; k < details.length(); k++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = details.getJSONObject(k);

        String uniqueId = jsonObject.getString("unique_id");
        String reciept = jsonObject.getString("Reciept");
        // Your Code ...

        DetailItem detailItem = new DetailIte();
        detailItem.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
        detailItem.setReciept(reciept);
        // Your Code ...

        detailItems.add(detailItem);
        // Your Code ...

    }
}
```

You Created :
    JSONArray details = object.getJSONArray("details");

So I don't Understand About :
    JSONObject detail = details.getJSONObject(i);

Change your code from this line :
    JSONArray details = object.getJSONArray("details");

Like :

```
JSONArray details = response.getJSONArray("details");
// List Of Custom Object Class 'DetailItem'
// It Contains fields of details object , unique_id and Reciept and etc
ArrayList<DetailItem> detailItems = new ArrayList<>();
if (details != null) {
    for (int k = 0; k < details.length(); k++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = details.getJSONObject(k);

        String uniqueId = jsonObject.getString("unique_id");
        String reciept = jsonObject.getString("Reciept");
        // Your Code ...

        DetailItem detailItem = new DetailIte();
        detailItem.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
        detailItem.setReciept(reciept);
        // Your Code ...

        detailItems.add(detailItem);
        // Your Code ...

    }
}
```

Comment: i have done this but data is not showing sequentioly,its looping many time

Comment: If not showing sequentially, maybe you user foreach ! it shows Data Out of Sorts.

Comment: Please Check it out

Comment: i think `unpaid_fees_details` is your List you need

Comment: yes that unpaid fees list shou display in diffrent type under fees receip rc1 or rc2 more

Comment: Yes

Upload File And give me the link , try my code Before